# Writing ArrayList to a file in a Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, file-io, jersey

I want to write an ArrayList file `data.txt` my code:

```
try{
    File destination = new File("data.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination));  
    os.writeObject(userList);
    os.close();
} catch....
```

This do's not trow any exceptions, just nothing.. Code runs normal. Is this code not going to work for a Web Service ? *(REST @ Jersey, pretty sure nothing to do with it)*

Comment: What is arrayList file? you mean .txt file, i guess. For .txt file you should better encapsulate with try/catch for your safety

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/ on how to upload a file in jersey.

Comment: Try and cache are all there, data.txt is a file, userList is an array List.

Comment: @smttsp Abobe please read. tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the updated code:

```
FileOutputStream userfile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\user.dat");
ObjectOutputStream userstream = new ObjectOutputStream(userfile);
userstream.writeObject(userList);
userstream.close();
```

Notice the "C:\data.dat" the code was not able to run with just data.dat ( no files where visible created on source folder.

For input the code is as follows:

```
ArrayList<User> dataList; // ** User is a custom Class
....
FileInputStream userfile = new FileInputStream("C:\\user.dat");
ObjectInputStream usersteam = new ObjectInputStream(userfile);
dataList = (ArrayList<User>)usersteam.readObject();
usersteam.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a file upload servlet rather than a JAX-RS enpoint.Its much easier in the long run. In relation to writing from an arraylist to a file,  This code will write it to a file and also check if the file has already been uploaded or not.

```
private List<File> files=new ArrayList<File>();
  private String filename="yourfilename.dat"

     private boolean fileHasAlreadyBeenUploaded() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    boolean hasFileAlreadyBeenUploaded=false;
    File currentfile=new File(fileName);
    if(!currentfile.exists()){
        currentfile.createNewFile();
        ObjectOutputStream output 
        = new ObjectOutputStream(
              new FileOutputStream(currentfile));
        files.add(currentFile);
        output.writeObject(currentFile);
        output.close();
        hasFileAlreadyBeenUploaded=false;
    }
    else{
         ObjectInputStream input 
            = new ObjectInputStream(
                  new FileInputStream(currentfile));

         files = (List<File>) (input.readObject());
         input.close();
        for(int i=0;i<files.size();i++){
            if(FileUtils.contentEquals(files.get(i), currentfile)){
                hasFileAlreadyBeenUploaded=true;
            }   
        }
        if(!hasFileAlreadyBeenUploaded){
            ObjectOutputStream output 
            = new ObjectOutputStream(
                  new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            files.add(currentfile);
            output.writeObject(currentfile);
            output.close();
        }
    }
    return hasFileAlreadyBeenUploaded;

}
```

and then you ca ndo whatever you want with it. With your web service you are better off using a Fileupload servlet that JAX-RS endpoint. The annotation @Webservlet will provide you with that endpoint

Please look at the following link for that example
[File upload servlet java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html)